# Where is the Skype for Business for Mac Log Location?

Tags: ms-office, skype

Microsoft has released the new [Skype for Business for Mac](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54108) product on October 26, 2016, as a replacement for the old Lync for Mac IM client.

On the "General" preferences page, the product contains a "Collect Logs" button. When I click that, nothing happens.

[image: General Preferences]

I'd like to know where the product stores its log files when a user clicks on this button. On previous Lync versions, the log files were stored under `~/Library/Logs`, but I did not see any Skype for Business log files there after clicking this button.

Where can I find the log files for this new client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this blog entry](https://johnacook.wordpress.com/2016/10/02/so-you-say-hate-the-lync-2011-mac-client/), the log location is:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.SkypeForBusiness/Data/Library/Logs/com.microsoft.SkypeForBusiness
```

This directory contains a file called `sfbmac.log`, which has the log information from the Skype for Business for Mac client.