# Skype for Business Mac Chat History Storage Location

Tags: mac, skype

I downloaded Skype for Business on Mac and I have tons of Chats saved, but there is no setting for deleting them after X amount of days or a way to delete them in mass. Currently, I have have to right click then delete on every single chat.

Does anyone know where the Chat history is stored on Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Open Finder and navigate to ~/Library/Application Support/Skype/.
The “~” sign means your home folder. To find your home folder, open Finder and in the main menu, select Go > Home or press Command (Apple) + Shift + H keys.
It is the folder that has your Skype Name.

An app restart may be required after making modifications.

Source: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10888/how-do-i-manage-my-conversation-history-in-skype-for-mac

Also, try this location: `/Library/Application Support/`, as there is a difference when the tilde sign is used.

Furthermore, the stores file can be found in `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.SkypeForBusiness`, which is the user folder according to [This Post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259442/where-is-the-skype-for-business-for-mac-log-location?rq=1)

Comment: I found the same article, but that is for Skype for Mac. There is no folder for Skype for Business in the Library/Application Support/ folder

Comment: Have you tried the /Library/Application Support/ file instead, there is a difference when the tilde sign is used.

Comment: If not, it is likely stored in the Exchange account that is linked to.

Comment: Also, have you seen [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259442/where-is-the-skype-for-business-for-mac-log-location?rq=1) it says to try `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.SkypeForBusiness`

Answer (score 1):

I put a small shell script together to do this, note in my testing this did not break anything but do this at your own risk.

Also this is Skype for Business Specific.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Kill existing Skype Session 
kill -9 `pgrep -f Skype`
# Change into the application data folder
cd ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.SkypeForBusiness/Data/Library/Application\ Support/com.microsoft.SkypeForBusiness
# Remove all Conversations
sqlite3 DataStore.sqlite "delete from Conversation"
# Remove all Conversation items  
sqlite3 DataStore.sqlite "delete from ConversationHistoryItem"
# Restart Skype
```

Comment: This method works temporarily. Once you logged in again, it will download the chat history from the server again! And it freezes again!